# Simultaneously setting PlotMarkers and Mesh

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[x + j], {j, {1, 4}}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"●", "○", "□", "◇"}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Works but when I introduce `Mesh->50`  the markers do not change

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[x + j], {j, {1, 4}}, {x, 1, 10, 0.3}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"●", "○","□", "◇"}, Mesh -> 30, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: This works as expected. `ListPlot[Table[Sin[x + j], {j, {1, 4}}, {x, 1, 10, 0.3}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[EmptyCircle]", "\[EmptySquare]"}, Joined -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post-process the output of `ListLinePlot` to modify the `Inset`s:

```
postProcess[markers_] := Module[{insets, 
    directives = Cases[#, {___, d_Directive, _Line} :> d, All]},
   insets = Inset[#, {0, 0}] & /@ (Style @@@ 
     Transpose[{Take[markers, Length@directives], directives}]); 
   # /. GeometricTransformation[i_, c_] :> 
    (GeometricTransformation @@@ Thread[{insets, Transpose@GatherBy[c, #[[1, 1]] &]}])] &

pmarkers = {"●", "○", "□", "◇"};

ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[x + j], {j, {1, 4}}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}], 
  PlotMarkers -> pmarkers, ImageSize -> Medium, Mesh -> 30] // 
 postProcess[pmarkers]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes It works but i think it is a bug that they cannot work together directly

Comment: @xinpei write to [Wolfram support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) and suggest that

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple solution. But sometimes there are wrong shown points.
Use `Mesh -> {Range[1, 100, 3]}` 
to set the x of mesh points.

`ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[x + j], {j, {1, 3, 2, 4}}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[EmptyCircle]", 
   "\[EmptySquare]", "\[EmptyDiamond]"}, Mesh -> {Range[1, 100, 3]}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]`